# HttpWebRequest, Redirects, chunked encoding error on live site, but works i IIS Express locally

Tags: c#, redirect, httpwebrequest, chunked-encoding

I have some code that creates a HTTP POST WebRequest with C# and posts some data to a https site. That site then redirects to a new URL and returns some data.

This works just fine on my local machine running IIS Express, but on my production server  throws an exception that says `Content-Length or Chunked Encoding cannot be set for an operation that does not write data.`.

This is what the code looks like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.UserAgent = userAgent;

StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
stOut.Write(data);
stOut.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseHtml = stIn.ReadToEnd();
        Uri downloadUri = GetDownloadUri(responseHtml);

        return downloadUri;
    }
}

throw new HttpException((int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
```

Any ideas what's wrong and what would a good solution be?

// Johan

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't need to set ContentLength. Try just taking that line out.

Comment: It wasn't needed, but I still got the same error. Even tried setting SendChunked = false.

Comment: Maybe in production, your data byte array is somehow empty?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In the production, all url are redirecting to https automatically. It does seem HttpWebRequest can not handle a redirect and throws this exception message.